# Issue getting :after element to show after container

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have inputs wrapped in a container `.input-wrap`. The inputs themselves are borderless and I am attempting to get an underline type effect with the `:after` element, however the `:after` element is not showing.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
.input-wrap {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
.input-wrap:after {
 margin-top: 5px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: purple;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
.contact_input {
 margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="email" class="contact_input" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Comment: add `content: '';` to the `:after` selector https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmBQao

Comment: I even tried that. Must have been a cache issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you need a wrapping element and `:after` pseudoselector just to have a purpple border under the input element? You can't do that with `input[type=text] { border: none;  border-radius: none; outline: none; border-bottom: 0.15em solid purple; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention by [Michael Coker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810262/issue-getting-after-element-to-show-after-container#comment74659657_43810262), the `content: '';` property is needed for the pseudo element to render.

```css
.input-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.input-wrap:after {
  content: '';
 margin-top: 5px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: purple;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
.contact_input {
  margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="email" class="contact_input" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Thanks to [amn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810262/issue-getting-after-element-to-show-after-container#comment74659864_43810262), you could also save yourself with that extra pseudo by simply give the wrapper a bottom border

```css
.input-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
}
.contact_input {
  margin: 30px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="contact_input" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="email" class="contact_input" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```